Conditional Execution of GitHub Actions Jobs Based on Modified Folders
I'm working on a project where I have two specific folders in my repository, folderA and folderB. I want to set up a GitHub Actions workflow that executes different jobs based on which of these folders was modified in a recent push or pull request.
My current setup looks like this:
name: Validation Run

on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - "website/**"
      - "admin/**"
    types:
      - opened

jobs:
  build-website:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./website
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "20"
      
  build-admin:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build Admin Website
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./admin
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "20"


to make it work your way it will get a bit expensive in terms of computational costs as you would need to create an initial job to checkout all the files of both folders and check each metadata info in each file to get the lastest date for each file.
Maybe another different approach could be a flag set in your repo in some text file from where you could read if what you need in that pull request is to do folderA or folderB.
